# I am getting segmentation failt while assigning the resourcemanager instance

Tags: android, c++, c++11

Here is my code snippet
I am trying to allocate the camera object from Create call of SomeCmaera.
but while executing the below code i am getting segmentation fault at object assignment in opencamera method.

MostImportant:
I cannot change the openCmaera method parameters its fixed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>
class ResourceManager {
public:
    void getCamerasource() {
        std::cout << "This is an ResourceManager getCamerasource." << std::endl;
    }
    void startvideo(){
        std::cout << "This is an ResourceManager startvideo." << std::endl;
    }
    void stopvideo(){
        std::cout << "This is an ResourceManager stopvideo." << std::endl;
    }
    releaseCameraSource() {}
};

class ICamera {
public:
    virtual void startvideo() =0;
    virtual void stopvideo() =0;
    virtual ~ICamera() = default;
};

class SomeCamera : public ICamera {
private:
    int cameraId;
    std::weak_ptr<ResourceManager> ResourceManagerInstance;
public:


    SomeCamera(const SomeCamera& ) = delete;
    SomeCamera& operator=(const SomeCamera&) = delete;
    SomeCamera(int id, std::shared_ptr<ResourceManager>& ebInstance) : cameraId(id), ResourceManagerInstance(ebInstance) {}
    static std::shared_ptr<SomeCamera> Create(int id, std::shared_ptr<ResourceManager>& ebInstance);
    virtual ~SomeCamera() = default;

    void showCamera() {
        std::cout << "Camera ID: " << cameraId << std::endl;
        auto service = ResourceManagerInstance.lock();
        std::cout << "Use count: " << service.use_count() << std::endl;
    }
    void startvideo(){
        std::cout << "SomeCamera startvideo." << std::endl;
         auto service = ResourceManagerInstance.lock();
         service->startvideo();
    }
    void stopvideo(){
        std::cout << "SomeCamerastopvideo." << std::endl;
         auto service = ResourceManagerInstance.lock();
         service->stopvideo();
    }
};

std::shared_ptr<SomeCamera> SomeCamera::Create(int id, std::shared_ptr<ResourceManager>& ebInstance){
    return std::make_shared<SomeCamera>(id,ebInstance);
}

class CameraController {
    private:
        std::unordered_map<int,std::weak_ptr<SomeCamera>> cameraslist;
    std::shared_ptr<ResourceManager> ebInstance;
public:
    CameraController() : ebInstance(std::make_shared<ResourceManager>()) {}

    void opencamera(int cameraId,  std::shared_ptr<ICamera>* obj) {
        std::cout << "opencamera "<< cameraId << std::endl;
        auto camera = SomeCamera::Create(cameraId,ebInstance);
        cameraslist.emplace(cameraId, camera);
        *obj = camera;
    }

    void closecamera(int cameraId) {
        std::cout << "close camera "<< cameraId << std::endl;
        cameraslist.erase(cameraId);
        std::cout << "Remaining camera "<< cameraslist.size() << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    CameraController enumerator;
    std::shared_ptr<ICamera>* obj1;
    std::shared_ptr<ICamera>* obj2;

    enumerator.opencamera(1,obj1);
    enumerator.opencamera(2,obj2);

    // (*obj1)->startvideo();
    // (*obj2)->startvideo();
    //sleep(10);
    // (*obj1)->stopvideo();
    // (*obj2)->stopvideo();

    enumerator.closecamera(1);
    enumerator.closecamera(2);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting segmentation fault while assignment of somecamera object into opencamera of cameracontroller

```
    void opencamera(int cameraId,  std::shared_ptr<ICamera>* obj) {
        std::cout << "opencamera "<< cameraId << std::endl;
        auto camera = SomeCamera::Create(cameraId,ebInstance);
        cameraslist.emplace(cameraId, camera);
        *obj = camera;
    }
```

Comment: If you write code with a pointer to a smart pointer, you know you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Yes, But as i mentioned i cannot change the Controller class opencamera params

Comment: Why are you using weak pointers?

Comment: This is an unintialised pointer, `std::shared_ptr<ICamera>* obj1;`. Here an uninitialised pointer is pass to a function `enumerator.opencamera(1,obj1);`. Here that uninitialised pointer is dereferenced `*obj = camera;`

Comment: I assume you are meant to code it like this `std::shared_ptr<ICamera> obj1;` and this `enumerator.opencamera(1,&obj1);` See how there are no raw pointers except the one you are forced to use by the signature of `opencamera`.

Comment: I'm guessing the creator of the class doesn't know that C++ have references, and attempt to emulate them the C way using pointers. If that's the case, then you should define `obj1` as a non-pointer, and use the pointer-to operator `&` when calling the function. I.e. `std::shared_ptr<ICamera> obj1;` and `enumerator.opencamera(1, &obj1)`

Comment: no no i cannot change the open camera params thats a problem otherwise i already used std::shared_ptr<ICamera>& in param

Comment: @Rajeev Two comments have explained how to fix the problem without changing `opencamera`.

Comment: std::shared_ptr<ICamera>* obj this i cannot change this is fixed

Comment: @Rajeev I see that. I'm not sure what the problem is. We have given you the answer, with the conditions you specified.

Comment: @Rajeev No-one is asking you to change `opencamera`

Comment: With our solution you don't have to change `opencamera` at all. All you have to do is update the variable declarations in the `main` function, and the ***calls*** to `opencamera`. But not the `opencamera` function itself, or its argument declarations.